# sql:update after sql:query (JSTL)

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, jstl

Struggling with what should be simple sql code.

First I have a select, this works correctly and produces a single row with a Duration column formatted as hh:mm:ss  (i.e 14:28:10)

```
<sql:query var="newquery" dataSource="jdbc/datbase">
                    select SEC_TO_TIME(secdiff) as Duration, assetid
                    from
                    (select TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  ts,  '<%=endt%>') as secdiff, assetid
                    from
                    (SELECT * FROM 
                    (select * from logs 
                    where assetid =${ param.assetid }
                    order by ts desc 
                    )AS T
                    )AS U
                    )AS V
                    group by assetid
                    </sql:query>
```

I then want to use the Duration to update the Duration value in the first row of another table, so I presume I have to set a variable first -

```
<c:forEach var="newrow" items="${newquery.rows}">
                    <c:set var="interval" value="${newrow.Duration}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
```

and then update only the first row in the table -

```
<sql:update var="anotherquery" dataSource="jdbc/database">
                    update duration SET Duration = ${interval} LIMIT 1;
                    </sql:update>
```

This fails either with a syntax error near LIMIT 1 or occasionally shows the interval variable has missing characters i.e. '30:28 instead of  '14:30:28' which may be a text variable formatting issue.

If I type these commands into MySQL Workbench they work without issue.

Any assistance appreciated.

Regards
Ralph

Comment: Ralph, it's a very bad practice to use the sql:query tags from JSTL. There are numerous articles about it. You better move the SQL code into the backend.

Comment: Thanks, but I have been using such tags for 14 years in multiple projects with no issues until now. I have already fixed fixed the current issue.